# How to apply style to child of element with active state

Tags: html, css

I have a button, when clicking on that button i make its background a colour via the :active selector. The button has children, 2 divs. The first of those divs, i want its font color to change to white when the button's active state triggers. Ive tried combining active with the child selector but cant seem to get this working, is it possible?

Here's a sample in codepen

https://codepen.io/starkbotha/pen/ExLYNWJ

```css
.my-button {
  width: 108px;
  height: 108px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 17px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
  
.my-button:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #21a086;
}
  
.my-button:active {
  background-color: #21a086;
  border: 2px solid #21a086;    
}

.my-button:active > button-value {
      color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="my-button">
  <div class="button-value">123</div>
  <div>My Title</div?
</button>
```

Comment: `.my-button:active > button-value` must be `.my-button:active > .button-value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot "." after calling your div class in css

```css
.my-button {
  width: 108px;
  height: 108px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 17px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
  
.my-button:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #21a086;
}
  
.my-button:active {
  background-color: #21a086;
  border: 2px solid #21a086;    
}

.my-button:active > .button-value {
      color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="my-button">
  <div class="button-value">123</div>
  <div>My Title</div?
</button>
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions based on a simple typo. Instead, comment accordingly and vote to close as typo.